# How to erase an Ubuntu USB Boot Drive

Tags: boot, usb

I used the Startup Disk Creator to create a USB Boot disk on my thumbdrive, but now I would like to clean the USB stick and re-use it at full capacity.  I don't have permission to erase or format the USB stick.  How can I clean this USB stick of all files?

Comment: Try **mkusb** according to the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266

Comment: See Colin Ian King's  answer here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/223598/how-to-format-a-usb-stick/223607

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223598/how-to-format-a-usb-stick)

Answer (score 1):

I would plug in the USB, open up gparted, select the correct /dev/sd*, unmount it, and erase the partition. When you open to gparted it will prompt you for your password however.

Comment: Arie vW is correct. `gparted` is the utility you want and one you should get reasonably familiar with. I use it a couple of times a month. Just make sure you don't format the wrong device.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to identify your USB Flash drive, so open up terminal and type `sudo fdisk - l`. It usually appears as the last one (in my case). BE CAREFUL! YOU MUST BE 100% SURE THAT YOU HAVE FOUND THE CORRECT ONE, OR ELSE YOU MAY LOSE DATA! Secondly, open up `gparted` and select the CORRECT DEVICE (in my case `sda`). Then delete all the partitions you find and create a new one, as filesystem I recommend using FAT32, but you can use whaterver you want, fill all the blanks and click OK. Lastly click APPLY and let it do it's job. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  I have my thumb drive back now.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)