# Unable to format USB: mkfs.vfat: unable to discover size of

Tags: partitioning, usb

**This question is not a duplicate. I followed the thread showing how to format usb but it didn't help (see below for details). Please also read the comments section**

I tried to follow [How to format a USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223598/how-to-format-a-usb-stick) thread to format my USB drive. However, `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1` still produces the following error.

```
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.vfat: unable to discover size of /dev/sdb1
```

The size of USB pendrive seems to be incorrect:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
--truncated--
sdb      8:16   1   7.2G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   239M  0 part
```

As you can see, the USB has size of 7,2G but there is one partition of size 239M.

I also tried `wipefs -a /dev/sdb` to erase all the partitions in USB thumb. Still, no luck.

Neither `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1`  or `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512` has worked as I'm still getting `mkfs.vfat: unable to discover size of /dev/sdb1`.

Comment: You create partitions first then you place a filesystem on the created partitions! your going about it the wrong way!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Could you write in what order I should approach this, please?

Comment: It is not duplicate. I did what the above thread suggested, but without luck.

Comment: Wipe the usb with `dd` then use `fdisk` to place a partition on it with the whole disk as the size. After place a filesystem on it with `mkfs.vfat`...

Comment: Then your usb is faulty!

Comment: My USB thumb was OK before I started playing with it.

Comment: Not a duplicate. My drive was 7,2GB and still is: `sdb      8:16   1   7.2G  0 disk`. Please do read carefully.

Comment: using gparted or something, you should try creating new partition table and then format

Answer (score 0):

Probably your partition table is corrupted.  The easy way to move forward is to open `gparted` and and in the top right go to `/dev/XdY`and select the disk you want to edit:

[image]

### This will destroy everything on the USB stick!

1. Go to the menu <kbd>Device</kbd>
2. Then <kbd>Create Partition Table</kbd>
3. Then <kbd>msdos</kbd>
4. Press  <kbd>OK</kbd>

Now you can create new partitions the way you want them...

If the above fails: **Your USB stick is toast!  Throw it away and buy a new one!**